# Colocar um datepicker em uma view mvc 5 com jquery ou similar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho essa razor em minha view:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            @Html.Label("Data de Agendamento", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" id="datepicker">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

E no final da página tenho esses scripts:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
}
```

Não sei como eu atribuo um ID para o campo: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`, coloquei o ID na `<div>`, mas quando renderizo não funciona e também não dá erro de js.

Tentei instalar esse pacote, mas dá erro:

> PM> Install-Package DatePickerHTMLHelper

EDIT1

No Dev Tools, peguei esse erro. Disse que não havia erros, mas peguei esse:

> GET http://localhost:55839/bundles/jqueryui 404 (Not Found)

EDIT2

Criei uma classe chamada datepicker assim:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker"
```

E fiz esse script

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
}
```

De qualquer forma não funciona. Não funfa nem por um decreto.

Comment: acredito que você não registrou os Bundles a pagina, normalmente isto é feito no evento `Application_Start` no arquivo `Global.asax` realizando alguma chamada envolvendo o `BundleTable.Bundles`.

Answer (score 3):

Você está confundindo as coisas. Esse pacote que você informou está criando um [htmlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx). Você deveria utilizar isso assim:

```
@Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.Date, "autoclose=true", "todayBtn=true", "todayHighlight=true")
```

Como mostra na própria [página do pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DatePicker.HTMLHelper/).

O script que você está querendo executar é de outro plugin.

Eu não utilizei esse que você demonstrou. Eu gosto muito [desse daqui](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), quando trabalho com bootstrap.

Para utilizar ele com [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) você realiza o download do projeto, o arquivo `.js` você [pode baixar o mesmo aqui](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js) e colocar em seu projeto. Feito isso, basta referenciar o script na `view` e pronto.

```
    <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            @Html.Label("Data de Agendamento", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id="dp" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

@section Scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#dp').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Após isso, você adiciona no **BundeConfig**, ou faz as alterações que julgar necessário.

Os arquivos completos você encontra no [gitHub do projeto](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

> Lembrando que dessa forma que coloquei irá funcionar somente se possui 1 elemento com o id "dp" (`id="#dp"`). Para utilizar mais de um, altere para classes (class=".dp") e mude a referencia no script para `$(".dp").datepicker();`.
>
> Lembrando também, que a forma que coloquei é apenas para "funcionar". Para manter o layout e os demais funcionalidades, faça o download completo do plugin (js + css).

Answer (score 1):

Amigão, não funciona o datepicker, ele nao abre, ele abre mas nao joga o valor no input?

Verifique se vc esta usando o BundleConfig com arquivos Minified ".min.js", pq ai ele nao faz o import.

No console, estoura algum erro?

vc colocou a classe datepicker no seu input?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker " } })
```